# Why javascript promise behave strange in case of using alert and console.log?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have below piece of code,

```js
function callPr() {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      res();
    }, 0);

  });
}

callPr().then(function() {
  alert('Promise Done'); //this alert popsup before loop run
  console.log('Promise Done'); //this console is printed after loop run
});

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

in above code, alert is poping up before the for loop is run, but

> console.log('Promise Done')

is printing after for loop completely run, why this is happening and if promise is asynchronous than why console.log is printing after for loop?

Comment: I can't reproduce. I see `Promise Done` in log only **after** alert.

Comment: For me, the loop runs first, then the alert pops up, then `Promise Done` is printed to console, which, I believe, should be the expected and correct behaviour.

Comment: Me too @31piy . Make it at least a 1 second timeout then you can see what you want OP.

Comment: I'm curious what browser you are using and what version.

Comment: `alert()` really messes up the timing of some things in Javascript because of its (unusual for Javascript) blocking nature.  Please don't ever use `alert()` when trying to debug timing issues.  Use only `console.log()` instead.

Comment: I tried with  putting document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; and it is running perfectly and asynchronously but only alert is mesing up.

@sorxrob i tried with 1000 ms and behaviour is same, I am trying it in chrome.

Answer (score 4):

> in above code, alert is poping up before the for loop is run

`alert` is definitely not being called until **after** those `console.log` calls, and that's what I see when I run your snippet on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. `then` handlers are **always** called asynchronously, but your `for` loop is in the same synchronous task as the call to `then` adding the callback, so the loop will definitely run before the `then` callback.

`alert` is a strange and anachronistic thing, though. I can imagine some browsers may not be *rendering* the results of the `console.log` until after you've dismissed the `alert`, given `alert`'s stop-the-UI behavior.

If that's happening in the browser you're using, here's a more reliable indicator of the sequence of things:

```js
var actions = [];

function callPr() {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      actions.push("resolving promise");
      res();
    }, 0);

  });
}

actions.push("creating promise");
callPr().then(function() {
  actions.push("promise done");
  // delay just to prove nothing else is waiting to happen
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(actions);
  }, 800);
});

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  actions.push("loop " + i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in fact yes promise is asynchronous but it is non blocked so the code will continue I think if you have a big loop you will notice that the console.log will be between the loop because .then and the loop will run together